# non-linear optimization for a linear classifier? (scikit-learn)

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, scikit-learn, optimization, kaggle

Using scikit-learn, why would you use bfgs optimization which is non-linear for a linear classifier as logistic regression? I am confused. Does the optimization method finds the optimum of the chosen score function? if so, which one? I can't choose it when defining the estimator. does the linearity or non-linearity of the score function depend on the model (whether it is linear or non-linear)?